# Rails: How to plan models and datebase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, model

Im pretty new to rails and I tried finding for an answer using rails with postgresql but maybe I am thinking it wrong or searching at the wrong places. So here goes

Lets say I want to do an app that tracks a user's lifestyle habits ( spending, savings, etc )

Do I do the following:

1. User model - email, password Lifestyle model - food, amount spent on
   food, transport, amount spent on  transport, bills, amount spent on 
   bills, etc....
2. User model - email, password Lifestyle_food model - amount spent,
   location, etc Lifestyle_transport model - amount spent, type of
   transport, etc etc models

For the above cases, I would like to allow the user to input their daily spendings, which I think will result in thousands of entries a year per user. With regards to the model planning, I am not sure which route should I be taking that will cause the minimal problems in the future.

**Situation A:** will result in a table with A LOT of columns and I am not sure if that is the optimal way for searches if a user wants to pin point his or her spending habits ( through several searches of views )

**Situation B:** will result in A LOT of models but each has fewer columns even if they were to be very detailed.

How should I define my models and database in rails?

There doesn't seem to be much material on the internet on how the planning should be done and the considerations ( Maybe a professional is required ), but for a novice like me, how should I proceed?

Comment: I usually focus on what is needed at the moment and build upon it keeping my goal in my mind. There's no way anyone can plan an entire project because you'll keep changing the functionalities. I use `git` which lets me create separate branches for new features and ensures that the new experimental code won't mess with my existing code.

Comment: This question is very broad and at least part of it not related directly to Ruby/Rails, but more data modelling.

Comment: Well it is because I am stuck at generating models and I am not sure if making models for every expenses (i.e food model, travel model, transport model, shopping model, and a model for every expenses that I can think of) or is it better to have a model called, maybe say "lifestyle" model and have columns and columns of the data?

Although it sounds more like a data modelling, since I am using rails, I am more concerned with the "Rails Way" of generating appropriate models. Kinda like how I search and found some articles on using has_many: through rather than has_many_and_belongs_to?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I agree this question is completely unrelated to RoR, I'm gonna answer with my opinion - because that's what this is an opinion

- `User` has_many:

  - `Months`

    - `month_index:integer:index YYYYMM (201706)`
    - `daily_hash:jsonb`

      - `{ 01: { food_expenditures: [ { amount: 24453, name: 'big mac', random_keys: with_whatever }, { rinse and repeat } ], travel_expenditures : [ same ], ... }, 02: { ... } }`

This would allow you to have 12 records per year * users, indexed on a integer column. So allowing user.month.find_by(month_index: 201704).daily_hash['02']['food_expenditures']

Does this present some problems? Yes, but it solves many others.

Comment: So essentially I am making a model called months?

Comment: I'm not saying for you to do it this way. I'm certainly no expert on the rails way, nor an expert on database design. I also see that patterns of programming, languages of choice and etc not only rest on the relative merits at solving a certain problem, but also on how a person thinks. If you make easier sense of a has_many, through you should do that. For me this is the easiest and most reasonable way of doing it without clogging the database. This does require things that fall off the "rails way" of doing it. It's a mixture of both relational and nosql.

Comment: @DGJH you would be doing a model named User, with a has_many relation ship to a model named Month. Because the way I see it is that I want to show the user expenditures on a given time-frame - that will be the biggest  part of it. IF instead you want to give a bigger emphasis to the type of expenditures (food, traveling) etc then probably you shouldn't do it this way. Because then you can't do user.lifestyle_foods and get all of them. So one of the steps is figuring out what you want to do with the data and then design the best solution for what you want to do.

Comment: Is there an online resource that specifically shows how to plan out the models in rails?

Comment: @DGJH I have no idea. You can easily find samples of executing model&relationships by visiting github repos for open source projects and see how they were solved.